# QGIS 3.16 offline work for search and rescue missions

Tags: qgis, offline, emergency-services

I want to use QGIS 3.16 for search and rescue missions. I'm looking for a way to work offline. I've already tried XYZ, but every attempt fails after several hours. I need very large layers from the entire state of Rhineland-Palatinate, as we can be alerted throughout the entire state.

Can you give me a good tip or show me a way that I can work offline?

Comment: OfflineEditing core plugin ? QField android app ? Input mobile app ? IntraMaps Roam ?

Comment: So you seek a offline basemap for that area?

Comment: You can download OpenStreetMap data for Germany (and worldwide) from Geofabrik, see: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html - than you can use this offline. And, as MrXsquared stated: QGIS natively works offline, just certain types of data like XYZ basemaps need an internet connection.

Comment: @MrXsquared yes i am looking for that